# factorization of a fourth degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

What could be the possible factorization of $$2a^4+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4$$? what term should be added

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $(a^2+b^2)^2-a^2b^2=a^4+a^2b^2+b^4$

$$(a^2-a b+b^2) (2 a^2+2 a b+b^2)$$

Comment: but sir how did you arrive at it?

Comment: Factorize $a^4+ab^3$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$a^4+a^2b^2+b^4+a(a^3+b^3)$$

$$=(a^2-ab+b^2)(a^2+ab+b^2)+a(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Comment: sir how did it come to your mind to factorize this way? please may i know your thinking process

Comment: @AdityaBidwai, Tried to utilize $a^4+a^2b^2+b^4$

Comment: sir you are fabulous...

Comment: i am gonna put some more qs and im in emergency... pls do answer my questions

Comment: thank you       sir aditya bidwai